# how to extract content in a word php

Tags: php

I want to cut a word in PHP but I only want the number. here is my word

```
$myword = BPT-11
```

I only want is `11`

How can i do this? using `split` or `substr`

Comment: Sure, give it a try. Just remember that split() is removed since PHP 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explode.

```
$myword = "BPT-11";
$exploded = explode("-", $myword);
echo $exploded[1];
//return 11
```

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php